# Validate email pattern with regex

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I googled a lot and the best and shortest answer that is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$
```

it makes validation until

somoene@hotmail

but if i type

`sdsdsdsd@hotmail...com`

`sdsdsdsd@hotmail.c`

`2222@hotmail.com`

all of this would be not catched by the regex that the email is invalid.

How can i validate this cases also with regex ?

```
<label for="email">Email <span class="error">*</span></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="contactUsForm.email" name="email" id="email" required
    #email="ngModel" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$" />
```

Comment: The only invalid email address in your list is `sdsdsdsd@hotmail...com`

Comment: Why is `2222@hotmail.com` invalid? The pattern would also match `-@hotmail.com`

Comment: because of the numbers in front

Comment: there are valid domains with emoji ... *never* go too fancy with emails validation, the only secure way to be sure is to send an email and have it confirmed back.

Comment: What you mean by confirmed back Andrea ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have chosen the shortest, you were giving up some of the complexities, like the ones you saw.

Let's divide your regex:

---

First part, before `@`:

`[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+` means one or more repetitions of letters and numbers, `_`, `.`, and also `+`, `-`

---

Second part, between `@` and `.`:

`[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` means one only letters and numbers and `-` (no dots allowed)

---

Third part, after `.`:

`[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+` means one or more letters, numbers, `-` and `.` - so you can have dozens of dots in this part.

---

If you want to avoid accepting `sdsdsdsd@hotmail...com` as valid, you must restrict the last part, by not accepting dots - `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+` would become `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` - but remember you will have problems with addresses with more than one dot, for example anything ending with `.co.uk`.

If you want to avoid accepting `hotmail.c` as valid, you must restrict at least two chars in the last part - `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+` would become `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,}`;

After those fixes you would still have problems. It is better to take longer and more detailed regexes for this work.

Here in stackoverflow there are quite a few.
Specific for javascript, in [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) (5399 upvotes), you have:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

And not specific, but even more complete, in [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) (2603 upvotes), you have:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Something is off with those escapes in the last regex

Comment: thanks for pointing out @GetSet, i have made some adjustements but i couldn't test it with angular where I believe is the place the question came from.

Comment: I dont know why, but somehow the regex is not right, when i put in the angular pattern it gives error. Can you please fix it ? The regex you sugggested ?

Comment: I don't know if it was the escaping, I had updated it using block code instead of inline code.